# How to Get Element's FQN in Sparx EA?

Tags: uml

In Sparx EA, I need to be able to copy and paste the fully-qualified name of a UML element, such as a class, property, or association. For example, the FQN for the class `Foo` might be `Package 1::Package 1.1::Foo`, and the FQN for the attribute in `Foo` called `name` might be `Package 1::Package 1.1::Foo::name`. In other tools, one can do this in the specification window. Is there a way to do this in Sparx EA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The nearest you get is Copy Node Path to Clipboard in the project browser context menu, which gives you a dot-separated path from the root node of the model tree.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can do a search and replace on the dots.